# Dee's extraordinary social security number

Tags: mathematics

Dee finds that she has an extraordinary social security number.  Its
nine digits contain all the digits from 1 to 9.  They also form a
number with the following characteristics:

1. When read from left to right the first two digits form a
   number divisible by two.
2. The first three digits form a number divisible by three.
3. The first four digits a number divisible by four, and so on,
   until the complete number is divisible by 9.

What is Dee's social security number?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

381654729, not really much explanation.

Comment: Solved! Good Job!